# Can I leave the sulphites out of my store bought wine kits

Tags: ingredients

Have trouble with any sulphites. I have all the wine making equip including a filter machine and have made 100 bottles of wine. Would love to try and leave the sulphites out but hate to wait 3 months to find out I ruined a batch. Basment stays around 60 degrees in the winter months.

Answer (score 1):

When I started making wine I asked the same question.  An experienced wine maker told me that I could leave it out, but the wine wouldn't keep as long and it wouldn't taste like what I expected it to taste like.  He was right.  So, I guess my answer would be that yes, you can leave them out, but you need to be aware of the effects of doing that.

Comment: Denny, can you provide any insight on to what those effects may be on the flavors by leaving them out? Wondering if there is a way to compensate for leaving them out to obtain the desired flavor.

Comment: It's been a long time, but IIRC the flavor seemed "flatter", if that makes any sense.  Kinda like when you don't salt food.